# Array and string conversion error

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to programming and I am creating a  simple website but i get stuck on this code!!

```
<?php
    $stats_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `id`=".$_SESSION['uid']."") or die(mysql_error());
    $stats = mysql_fetch_assoc($stats_get);
?>
```

I get an error of array to string conversion error!
This file is included in the header file! And this is supposed to get the stats of the user if they are logged in. Sessions are also already defined at the main page.

Comment: `$_SESSION['uid']` is an array obviously. `var_dump($_SESSION['uid'])`

Comment: On a side note mysql_query is deprecated in php 5.5 and use something newer and safer like PDO http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

Answer (score -1):

The Query should be like below:

```
$stats_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE id=" . $_SESSION['uid']) or die(mysql_error()); $stats = mysql_fetch_assoc($stats_get);
```

Comment: Why? What have you changed? What difference should it make? This looks like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer. The only differences I can see if that you aren't appending an empty string to the end (sensible, but not significant) and have stopped quoting any of the table/column names (not a good idea).